# Populate PDF Combo Box Via VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, combobox, acrobat

I have the below code to populate a combobox in a PDF document. As far as I can tell, the code is correct, according to the [Acrobat Forms API Reference](https://www.pdfill.com/download/FormsAPIReference.pdf)

[image]

However the code fails on the `PopulateListOrComboBox` call with this error:

> Method 'PopulateListOrComboBox' of object 'IField' failed

```
Dim acroApp As Acrobat.acroApp
Set acroApp = New Acrobat.acroApp

Dim myForm As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
Set myForm = New Acrobat.AcroAVDoc

Dim bOK As Boolean
bOK = myForm.Open("C:\Users\sholtzman\downloads\wordFormTest.pdf", "temp")

Dim theRealForm As AFORMAUTLib.AFormApp
Set theRealForm = New AFORMAUTLib.AFormApp

Dim pdField As AFORMAUTLib.Field
Set pdField = theRealForm.Fields.Add("triaCoverage", "combobox", 0, 10, 20, 100, 200)

Dim items(2) As String
items(0) = " "
items(1) = "Accept"
items(2) = "Reject"

pdField.PopulateListOrComboBox items
```

Furthermore, I tested this piece of code as well to try to fill it, but it also failed with the error:

> Automation error Unspecified error

```
Dim myPDForm As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Set myPDForm = myForm.GetPDDoc

Dim jso As Object
Set jso = myPDForm.GetJSObject

jso.getField("triaCoverage").setItems(1) = " "
```

Lastly, when I save and close the document after adding the combobox, I can go in 
and set list values manually. Any ideas how I can get this to work through code?

Comment: I'm reading about PDF COM first time, so just a guess. I see `arrItems` is somewhat associated with a _Variant&_ type: may be you have to declare `Dim items As Variant` and populate `items = Array(" ", "Accept", "Reject")`?

Comment: @DisplayName - Thanks. I double-checked what you suggest and I get a `Invalid Procedure Call or Argument` error with Variant type.

Comment: sorry, really can't be more of more help

Comment: may be [THIS](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2167205) can help you

Comment: @DisplayName - Interesting find. Thank you. I may try that out.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and have found one answer just now by replacing the line:

```
jso.getField("triaCoverage").setItems(1) = " "
```

with

```
jso.getField("triaCoverage").setItems(items)
```

However, I prefer to use the PopulateListOrComboBox method if at all possible, so i will leave this unanswered for some time.